# Can anyone explain centrifugation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, density, centrifugal-force, fluid-statics

Why larger particles tend to remain at the bottom level of the test tube while the smaller particles form a layer above the larger particles?

Comment: Just google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason large particles tend to be at the bottom is because their sedimentation rate is greater.

If $r$ is the radius of the particle the mass of a particle, and hence the downwards force, is proportional to $r^3$. However if we assume [Stokes flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_law), which is likely to be the case in a centrifuge, then the viscous drag is proportional to $r$. That means the net downwards force on the particles is proportional to $r^2$.

The result is that larger particles settle faster, and that's why you find the largest particles at the bottom of the tube.

Answer (score 2):

centrifugation has nothing to do with particle sizes. it segregates particles by differences in their density, not their size. The densest particles wind up at the bottom of the centrifuge tube; the least dense at the top.

Comment: and That is due to density but why?

Comment: a force like gravity but thousands of times stronger is experienced by the  particles as they are whirled around. if they are denser than the liquid in which they float, they quickly sink. if less dense, they quickly rise.